# Gmail 5.0+: How to get label information for Gmail's Exchange feature

Tags: android, email, gmail

This is how to get label information for Gmail accounts: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html

Recently, Google announced Gmail 5.0 with exchange feature. How can we see label information for exchange accounts?

For getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures() method, I had to change ACCOUNT_TYPE_GOOGLE to ACCOUNT_TYPE_EXCHANGE and features=null in order to get exchange account.

```
private static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE_GOOGLE = "com.google";
private static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE_IMAP = "com.google.android.gm.legacyimap";
private static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE_EXCHANGE = "com.google.android.gm.exchange";
AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures(ACCOUNT_TYPE_EXCHANGE, null,
                new AccountManagerCallback<Account[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Account[]> future) {
                        Account[] accounts = null;
                        try {
                            accounts = future.getResult();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Got OperationCanceledException", e);
                        }

                    }
                }, null /* handler */);
```

After getting Account[] information, here's the code to get label information:

```
final Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("account", sAccount);
getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, args, this);
```

Here's the code to get label information:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (data != null) {
        data.moveToFirst();
        String name = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(GmailContract.Labels.NAME));
        String unread = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS));
        String total = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(GmailContract.Labels.NUM_CONVERSATIONS));
        String uri = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(GmailContract.Labels.URI));
    }
}
```

For Gmail accounts, I get label information back (name, unread, total, uri, etc). However, for exchange accounts, I don't get any information back.
Is there a way?